# In Transfer Learning ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I am Practicing on **Transfer Learning** with Iris dataset.

For the following code I get the following error messege:

> Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type
> float)

I Need help in solving this error.

> Below the imported libraries

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
```

> read the csv file using pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv("Iris.csv", na_values=['NA', '?'])
df.columns
#output of df.colums
Index(['Id', 'SepalLengthCm', 'SepalWidthCm', 'PetalLengthCm', 'PetalWidthCm',
       'Species'],
      dtype='object')
```

> convert into numpy array for classification

```
x = df[['SepalLengthCm', 'SepalWidthCm', 'PetalLengthCm', 'PetalWidthCm', 'Species']].values
dummies  = pd.get_dummies(df['Species'])   #classification
species = dummies.columns
y = dummies.values
```

> Build the Neural Network,

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim = x.shape[1], activation= 'relu'))   #Hidden Layer-->1
model.add(Dense(25, activation= 'relu'))     #Hidden Layer-->2
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation= 'softmax'))     #Output
```

> Compile the NN model

```
model.compile(loss ='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer ='adam')
```

**Fit the model and Please concern in this part**

```
model_fit=model.fit(x,y, verbose=2, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=3)
```

> Error is given below,

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-0ff464178023> in <module>()
----> 1 model_fit=model.fit(x,verbose=2, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=3)

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     96       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
     97   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 98   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
     99 
    100 

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
X = np.asarray(x).astype(np.float32)

model_fit=model.fit(X,y, verbose=2, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=3)
```

It seems that one of the column is not supported. So just convert it to numpy array with data type float.

Note you define `x` in a wrong way that contain the class. It should be:

```
x = df[['SepalLengthCm', 'SepalWidthCm', 'PetalLengthCm', 'PetalWidthCm']].values
```

Comment: @ImdadulHaque did you also noticed the note? regarding the building of `x`